# How to pass a array into webapi function?

Tags: angularjs

I want to pass an array into webapi.

Here is my function for getting checkbox selected items in `albumNameArray`.

```
$scope.Delete = function () {
        debugger
        $scope.albumNameArray = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.InboxList, function (CU) {
            if (CU.selected) $scope.albumNameArray.push(CU.InboxMailID);
        })
    }
```

Now I want to send the `albumNameArray` into webapi function. I have modified the delete function but it is not working, what is wrong in my code?

```
$scope.Delete = function () {
        debugger
        $scope.albumNameArray = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.InboxList, function (CU) {
            if (CU.selected) $scope.albumNameArray.push(CU.InboxMailID);
        }).$http({
        url: "MailRoute/DeleteSelecetedEmail",
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'POST',
        data: albumNameArray,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }

    }).success(function (response) {
        debugger
        if (response != null) {

        }

    })
      .error(function (error) {
          alert(error);
      });
}
```

Comment: paste your WebAPI code as well here

Comment: I think this is model. You must paste Controller code.

Comment: public HttpResponseMessage Delete(HttpRequestMessage request, [FromBody]GetAllInbox obj)
    {

        if (something!= 0)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }

        return response;
    }

Comment: actually the array is not going to my angularjs function thats the problem

Comment: first of all you are passing array, so must have received array in WebAPI parameter. Second check that your Array is not null before passing to function

Comment: array is not null i have checked.i think the problem is on the function.some bracket problem.i have checked with debugger.but the data is not going on the webapi function.can you modify my delete function please?

Comment: if you have postman you can check WebAPI in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(string data)
{
    if (something!= 0)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
    return response;
}
```

If this is not working Try with List

Answer (score 0):

this is the model class i have declared

```
public class GetAllInbox
    {
        public string data{ get; set; }
   }
```

the webpai fuction is shown below

```
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(HttpRequestMessage request, [FromBody]GetAllInbox obj)
    {

        if (something!= 0)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }

        return response;
    }
```

here is my webapi code.

Comment: public List<string> data{ get; set; }
try with this

Comment: actually the array is not going to my angularjs function thats the problem